# Return a zero if cell is blank when referencing an additional sheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet with this:
`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Sheet1'!U$5,Sheet2!U2)),1,0)`
Which returns a score of `1` in `Sheet2`, when `Sheet1` `U5` cell matches the data in `U2` in `Sheet2`.

How do I add to this formula to get it to first do the above, but to return a `0` in `Sheet2` if the cell in `Sheet1` is empty? At the moment it is returning a `1` in `Sheet2` when the cell in `Sheet1` is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add another if statement that checks if the content is non empty and returns 0 if not.

```
=IF(LEN('Sheet1'!U$5),
    IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Sheet1'!U$5, Sheet2!U2)), 1, 0), 
    0)
```

`LEN()` can be used as a shortcut for `NOT(ISBLANK())` for all purposes I've encountered.